# How can I return a sorted list of related records?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy classes:

```
class Survey(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='survey', lazy='dynamic')

class Questions(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    survey_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('survey.id'))
    bank_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('bank.id'))

class Bank(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='bank', lazy='dynamic')
```

So, surveys and banks have questions and the order of questions depends on the question's parent bank.

Given a survey, how can I get a list of the questions in ascending order by the order field? I can get the questions easily enough, and if necessary, I can sort them after that, but I'm wondering if there's a more direct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the behaviour given the secondary table but you can pass `order_by` into `relationship()`, for example:

```
 questions = db.relationship('Question', order_by='asc(Question.bank.order)' ... )
```